# Make directed graph run clockwise and change its orientation

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, networkx

The following code generates a circular directed graph with `networkx`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def make_cyclic_edge(lst):
    cyclic = []
    for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
        if i+1 < len(lst):
            cyclic.append((elem, lst[i+1]))
        else:
            cyclic.append((elem, lst[0]))

    return cyclic


def cycle_diagram(generate, inhibit, organ_func=False, plot=False):
    """Generate element cycle diagram with Networkx. """

    G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    for pair in generate:
        G.add_edge(*pair, color="g", group="generate")

    for pair in inhibit:
        G.add_edge(*pair, color="r", group="inhibit")

    pos = nx.circular_layout(G, center=(0, 0))

    edges_to_adjust = []

    if organ_func:
        fig = plt.figure(2, figsize=(5, 5), dpi=200)

        edges_to_adjust = [("LI", "GB", 0), ("LI", "GB", 1), ("GB", "TE", 0), ("TE", "LI", 0),
                           ("ST", "BL", 0), ("BL", "SI", 0)]

        for edge in edges_to_adjust:
            G.remove_edge(*edge)

    color = list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'color').values())

    if organ_func:
        nx.draw(
            G, pos=pos,
            with_labels=True,
            font_size=16,
            node_size=800,
            node_color='#C6DDCB',
            connectionstyle=f"arc3, rad=0.0",
            edge_color=color,
        )

        nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,
                               pos=pos,
                               node_size=800,
                               edgelist=edges_to_adjust,
                               connectionstyle=f"arc3, rad=0.6",
                               edge_color=["r"]*len(edges_to_adjust),
                               )

    else:

        fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 4), dpi=200)

        nx.draw(
            G, pos=pos,
            with_labels=True,
            font_family='AR PL KaitiM Big5',
            font_size=16,
            node_size=800,
            node_color='#C6DDCB',
            connectionstyle=f"arc3, rad=0.235",
            edge_color=color,
        )

    if plot:
        plt.show()

    return G


ORGAN_FUNC = (
    "SP",
    "LU",
    "PC",
    "LI",
    "TE",
    "GB",
    "LR",
    "KI",
    "HT",
    "SI",
    "BL",
    "ST",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_GEN = make_cyclic_edge(ORGAN_FUNC)

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_A = (
    "BL",
    "SI",
    "LI",
    "GB",
    "ST",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_Am = (
    "LI",
    "GB",
    "TE",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_B = (
    "SP",
    "KI",
    "PC",
    "HT",
    "LU",
    "LR",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_C = (
    "LR",
    "PC",
    "HT",
    "LU",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_D = (
    "BL",
    "TE",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_inhibit_list = [
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_A,
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_Am,
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_B,
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_C,
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_D,
                             ]

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT = []
for cycle in ORGAN_FUNC_inhibit_list:
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT += make_cyclic_edge(cycle)


ORGAN_FUNC_CYCLE = cycle_diagram(ORGAN_FUNC_GEN, ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT, organ_func=True, plot=True)
```

[image: Generated graph]

I would like to:

1. Make the arrows along its circumference run clockwise.
2. Rotate the graph so that `"BL"` is at the top.

like so (organ code-names differ slightly):

[image: Desired image setting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the most elegant, but here's one approach that works. I made the following changes to your `cycle_diagram` function. I added optional arguments `top` (to specify the top node) and `flip` (to specify whether to flip coordinates horizontally). Within the code, I added the following in after the layout `pos` is defined.

```
    if top:
        c,s = pos[top]
        R_mat = np.array([[s,-c],[c,s]])
        for k,v in pos.items():
            pos[k] = R_mat@v
    if flip:
        for k,v in pos.items():
            pos[k][0] *= -1
```

`R_mat` is a rotation matrix that rotates the point at `pos[top]` to the point (0,1), assuming that all points in the layout have magnitude 1 (which is indeed the case when the `circular_layout` function is used).

Here's the full script, with the additions.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

def make_cyclic_edge(lst):
    cyclic = []
    for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
        if i+1 < len(lst):
            cyclic.append((elem, lst[i+1]))
        else:
            cyclic.append((elem, lst[0]))

    return cyclic


def cycle_diagram(generate, inhibit, organ_func=False, plot=False, top=None, flip=False):
    """Generate element cycle diagram with Networkx. """

    G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    for pair in generate:
        G.add_edge(*pair, color="g", group="generate")

    for pair in inhibit:
        G.add_edge(*pair, color="r", group="inhibit")

    pos = nx.circular_layout(G, center=(0, 0))
    
    if top:
        c,s = pos[top]
        R_mat = np.array([[s,-c],[c,s]])
        for k,v in pos.items():
            pos[k] = R_mat@v
    if flip:
        for k,v in pos.items():
            pos[k][0] *= -1

    edges_to_adjust = []

    if organ_func:
        fig = plt.figure(2, figsize=(5, 5), dpi=200)

        edges_to_adjust = [("LI", "GB", 0), ("LI", "GB", 1), ("GB", "TE", 0), ("TE", "LI", 0),
                           ("ST", "BL", 0), ("BL", "SI", 0)]

        for edge in edges_to_adjust:
            G.remove_edge(*edge)

    color = list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'color').values())

    if organ_func:
        nx.draw(
            G, pos=pos,
            with_labels=True,
            font_size=16,
            node_size=800,
            node_color='#C6DDCB',
            connectionstyle=f"arc3, rad=0.0",
            edge_color=color,
        )

        nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,
                               pos=pos,
                               node_size=800,
                               edgelist=edges_to_adjust,
                               connectionstyle=f"arc3, rad=0.6",
                               edge_color=["r"]*len(edges_to_adjust),
                               )

    else:

        fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 4), dpi=200)

        nx.draw(
            G, pos=pos,
            with_labels=True,
            font_family='AR PL KaitiM Big5',
            font_size=16,
            node_size=800,
            node_color='#C6DDCB',
            connectionstyle=f"arc3, rad=0.235",
            edge_color=color,
        )

    if plot:
        plt.show()

    return G


ORGAN_FUNC = (
    "SP",
    "LU",
    "PC",
    "LI",
    "TE",
    "GB",
    "LR",
    "KI",
    "HT",
    "SI",
    "BL",
    "ST",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_GEN = make_cyclic_edge(ORGAN_FUNC)

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_A = (
    "BL",
    "SI",
    "LI",
    "GB",
    "ST",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_Am = (
    "LI",
    "GB",
    "TE",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_B = (
    "SP",
    "KI",
    "PC",
    "HT",
    "LU",
    "LR",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_C = (
    "LR",
    "PC",
    "HT",
    "LU",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_D = (
    "BL",
    "TE",
)

ORGAN_FUNC_inhibit_list = [
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_A,
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_Am,
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_B,
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_C,
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT_D,
                             ]

ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT = []
for cycle in ORGAN_FUNC_inhibit_list:
    ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT += make_cyclic_edge(cycle)


ORGAN_FUNC_CYCLE = cycle_diagram(ORGAN_FUNC_GEN, ORGAN_FUNC_INHIBIT, 
                                 organ_func=True, plot=True, top = "BL", flip = True)
```

The result I get:

[image]

Comment: Nice hack using matrix transformation!

Comment: @Ben Grossmann, I am trying to learn graph network and use that in a project. Any good tutorial material I can use?